# Is there a way to get "DNS DRAC Name" value from dell idrac8 using ipmitool?

Tags: ipmitool

As a part of automating server self discovery I am trying to fetch network details of the idrac. I can fetch ipV4 network settings using "ipmitool lan print" command. But I want to fetch "DNS DRAC Name" value as well which we are setting manually. Can it be queried using any of the ipmitool options?

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find it. Neither with the various ipmitool commands I tried, nor with SNMP.

However, there is a setting to let it register itself in the DNS. And your DHCP server may also be configured to do it anyway.

So I cannot read the value from the machine, but I can get the name with reverse DNS:

```
idracIP=192.168.10.10
host $idracIP
# or
dig +short -x $idracIP
```